# Example of a faithful irreducible module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a non trivial simple ring. I am trying to show that there is a faithful irreducible left $R$-module.

Is the ring $R$ considered as a left module over itself such a module? I think it's faithful since the ring map $R \to R_\ell: r\mapsto (r_\ell:a\mapsto ra))$ has zero kernel  but I am not sure that it's irreducible. How do you show that it has no proper left ideals?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think $R$ needs to satisfy some chain condition for this to be true.

Comment: Sorry, my answer assumed commutative rings so I deleted it.  I wasn't thinking about the non commmutative case.

Comment: If $R$ is not a division ring, then (the left regular module) $R$ is not an irreducible module over itself. So for instance, if $R$ is the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field, then $R$ is simple, so every module is faithful, but its simple modules all have dimension $2$ over the field, while $R$ itself has dimension $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a simple ring $R$, *every* nonzero unital module is faithful.

So just take any simple $R$ module $S$ and you have an irreducible faithful module.

Comment: Can you please explain, why a simple module over $R$ must exist? Is $R$ assumed to be left-artinian?

Comment: @dune Simple modules exist because maximal right  (and left) ideals exist. The quotient of the ring by such a right ideal is simple. This is the case if R has identity, anyhow. (At least, I was going on the impression the user probably wanted identity)

Comment: Oh, right. I mixed up simple modules and simple left ideals. Thank you!